# Dynamic fields for django model using `__init_subclass__`

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, model-view-controller, django-models

How do I copy over a models fields dynamically to subclasses (with variations...) using `__init_subclass__` I've tried this:

```
 @classmethod
 def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
 ...
 for field, field_name in vars(base_model).items():
      if isinstance(DeferredAttribute):
          field.contribute_to_class(cls, new_name, changed_field)
 ...
```

But, `DeferredAttribute` doesn't have the `contribute_to_class` method. Moreover, I can't use the EVA pattern etc. It specifically has to be this method if possible.

Using `vars` because since this is `__init_subclass__` then the `model._meta.get_fields()` doesn't actually exist yet...

I can do:

```
  for extension in extensions:
      for field in base_model._meta.local_fields:
          copied_field = field.__copy__()
          if not cls._meta.abstract:
              copied_field.contribute_to_class(cls, new_name)
```

But, then this doesn't show up in the model at all in the models `local_fields` attribute. So, it doesn't look like `contribute_to_class` is working.

Ive tried using the higher level `add_to_class` i.e. - `cls.add_to_class(copied_field, new_name)` and same affect on the extended model.

Comment: Have you fixed the issue yet? I want to do a similar thing and I am curious about where you actually put `__init_subclass__`. I tried to create a mixin and let my models inherit from both `models.model` and the mixin that defines `__init_subclass__` but `__init_subclass__` is called before even `_meta` is defined, so the method cannot get any attributes that are declared fields.